# Pure CSS Animated Modal/Lightbox

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I'm using CSS Animated Modal from PHP Academy's tutorial. I already did this in other project, but now I don't know why isn't work. The problem looks to be target selector, don't work when I click on link. Can you help me?

So, this happens in this page: http://www.sarosacramento.com/v2/#produtos
Te result should be this, but instead he links like div is in sequence (in html it is): http://www.sarosacramento.com/v2/#oranges

```css
/*******************

Produtos

*********************/

#produtos * {
 border:none;
 text-decoration:none;
 }

#produtos {
 position:relative;
 min-height:660px; 
 background-color:#9C3;
 }

.product {
 display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
 text-align:center;
 width:90%;
 
 -webkit-justify-content: space-around; 
   justify-content: space-around;
 
 margin-top:100px;
 }
 
.prod-it img {
 height:250px;
 width:250px;
 margin:30px auto;
 border-radius:50%;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
 }
 
.prod-it img:hover {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Opera */
     transform:rotate(360deg);
}
 
.prod-it h2 a {
 position:relative;
 color:#360;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);
 padding:5px 10px;
 border:2px solid #360;
 border-radius:10px;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
 }
 
.prod-it h2 a:hover {
 background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}




/*******************************************************************************************************
******************      MODAL CSS      ***************************************************************
*********************************************************************************************************/

.modal-container {
 position:fixed;
 background-color:#ddd;
 border:1px solid #333;
 width:70%;
 max-width:700px;
 min-height:350px;
 max-height:90%;
 overflow:hidden;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 padding:20px;
 border-radius:5px;
 z-index:200;
 
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
 
 -webkit-transition:transform 200ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition:transform 200ms ease-out;
 transition:transform 200ms ease-out;
 }
 
.modal:before {
 content:"";
 position:fixed;
 display:none;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 z-index:199;
 }
 
.modal:target:before {
 display:block;
 }

.modal:target .modal-container {
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
 


.modal-close {
 display:none;
 font-family:"Open Sans", "Bebas Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:700;
 color:#fff;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 z-index:201; 
 background-color:#9C3;
 margin:0;
 padding:5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 border-radius: 8px;
 }
 
.modal-close:hover {
 background-color:#333;
 color:#ccc;
 }
 
.modal:target .modal-close {
 display:block;
 }
 
#modal-close {
 }
```

```html
 <!-- Produtos -->
 <div id="produtos" class="animatedParent" data-sequence='500'>
    
     <header>
   <h1>Produtos</h1>
  </header>
  
     <div class="product">
        <div class="prod-it p1 animated bounceInUp" data-id='1'><a href="#oranges"><img src="img/item-1.jpg" /></a><br /><h2><a href="#oranges">Laranjeiras</a></h2></div>
        <div class="prod-it p2 animated bounceInUp" data-id='2'><a href="#lemons"><img src="img/item-2.jpg" /></a><br /><h2><a href="#lemons">Limoeiros</a></h2></div>
        <div class="prod-it p3 animated bounceInUp" data-id='3'><a href="#apples"><img src="img/item-3.jpg" /></a><br /><h2><a href="#apples">Macieiras</a></h2></div>
     </div>
        
        <div class="modal" id="oranges">
         <div class="modal-container">
            <a href="#modal-close" class="modal-close">X Fechar</a>
             <p>I love cats</p>
             </div>
        </div>
            
  <div class="modal" id="lemons">
         <div class="modal-container">
            <a href="#modal-close" class="modal-close">X Fechar</a>
             <p>I love cats</p>
   </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal" id="apples">
         <div class="modal-container">
            <a href="#modal-close" class="modal-close">X Fechar</a>
             <p>I love cats</p>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal with #(apples, oranges..) are in the center of the screen. Therefore when you click the icon of apples for example, it offsets you to that middle screen..

Also the modal doesn't show up because you returned false in the a.click() in **main.js**.

So to fix the whole problem..

**1.Go to main.js and scroll down and find this code, and put "return true" like this:**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        if($(this).attr('name') == "modal") return true; 
            else return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**2. Find your style.css and put this piece of code:**

```
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index:3;
    }
```

So this style does that

> scrollTop: target.offset().top

Offsets 0 from top, so your page doesnt go down when you click on link.

Cheers! :)

*Edit: I set the return true to other function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know almost nothing about javascript so it's hard to me too find problems like this. But now, this change damage the initial effect of smooth scrooll. It's possible to fix this?

Comment: Hey, sorry for late answer.. Put this instead of that "return true": 
    `if($(this).attr('name') == "modal") return true;
       else return false;`
Also you have to add on every <a href='' that triggers the modal name modal.. So `<a href="oranges" name="modal">`. Remember that you have 2 a hrefs for one modal, so add it on both! It's a little hack but it works like a charm, cheers! :) @JoãoSaro

Comment: Perfect. It's working now. :D Just a little tremble smooth from top to "empresa", I don't know why, but I don't think it's because of this.

Comment: Hmm I don't know. I think it's because too much content, animations, videos.. On my macbook it's smooth :)